# Mapping behaves differently than manually typing

Tags: key-bindings

If `ddkP` is typed in normal mode on the first line then nothing happens¹. If `:nnoremap + ddkP` is executed and then `+` is pressed, the line is deleted. Why?

¹(if file only has one line then a new empty line appears but otherwise the behaviour is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mappings abort on errors, and trying to move further « up » than the first line is an error, so the `P` never gets executed.

I have some [other « bubble » mappings](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/bubble.vim) you might be interested in.