# Why do mappings abort on errors?

Tags: key-bindings, error

According to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24358/27528), if a error occurs during the execution of a mapping, its execution is aborted. Why is it like that and:

1) Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

2) In the case of the above answer, the error is invisible: if i press up in the first line in vim, theres no notification of an error, and `:echo errmsg` also doesn't display anything new. How to view those errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented under [`:help map-error`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-error):

> Note that when an error is encountered (that causes an error message or beep)
>   the rest of the mapping is not executed.  This is Vi-compatible.

Regarding this part of your question:

> 2) In the case of the above answer, the error is invisible: if i press up in the first line in vim, theres no notification of an error, and `:echo errmsg` also doesn't display anything new. How to view those errors?

Your [previous question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/23360/18609) involved using `k` on the first line of the document. That falls under category of producing a "beep", so you don't really get a notification that this command failed.

(It's the same outside of a mapping. If you press `k` on line 1, you don't really get an error message anywhere, it just "beeps" [but you might not hear it since they're quite possibly disabled] and otherwise does nothing.)

> 1) Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

There's [`:silent!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Asilent):

> When `!` is added, error messages will also be skipped, and commands and *mappings will not be aborted* when an error is detected.

But it's often too coarse, since it hides errors globally. Also, if you want to use it with normal mode commands, you also need `:normal!`. And you typically also need to mark your mapping with `<silent>` to prevent it from displaying the `:silent! normal! ...` in the command-line.

This would work to prevent the error in the mapping from your [previous question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/23360/18609), when it's run from the first line:

```
:nnoremap <silent> + :silent! normal! ddkP<CR>
```

But I wouldn't actually recommend using this for the mapping, as there are better solutions to it.

I guess the right answer is: You should write your mappings defensively, so that errors won't happen where you don't want them. A better approach:

```
:nnoremap <expr> + line('.') > 1 ? 'ddkP' : ''
```

This also lets you handle the case of running it on the last line of the buffer, in which case deleting the line will also move you one line up:

```
:nnoremap <expr> + line('.') == line('$') ? 'ddP' : line('.') > 1 ? 'ddkP' : ''
```

But even then, the [«bubble» mappings](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/bubble.vim) in [@D.BenKnoble's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24358/18609) using the [`:move`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Amove) command are a much more superior way to accomplish the same:

> ```
> " Bubble single lines up and down
> nnoremap - :.move +1
> nnoremap _ :.move -2
> " Bubble lines up and down in visual mode
> vnoremap - :'move '>+1 \| normal! gv
> vnoremap _ :'move '
> ```

One final point is that breaking execution on error for mappings and macros is actually a *feature*. For example, if you have a recursive mapping or macro, if you want to process each line, you know you can simply move on to the next line and call the mapping/macro again, since you know there's a stop condition at the point where you can't move on to the next line again (end of the file.)

Similarly for when you're doing searches with `/` or `?`. You know the mapping/macro will stop if you search for a term that doesn't exist anymore. Or if you set `'nowrapscan'`, you know you'll stop at the last match of the file.

In both of those cases, silently continuing after a failure would be really problematic, since it would make it much harder to implement recursion and it would potentially keep executing commands meant for a match when no match was found.

So, in short, try to prevent errors when you can. Try to write your mappings in a way that is unlikely to trigger errors. Use breaking on errors to your favor.